Serve a .py file?
I wanted to set up a Brython demo of my Python project. Unfortunately, this file is giving me a 404 even though it's in the repo and the root is set to /:
https://d33mobile.github.io/pyflate2/pyflate/__init__.py
Does it mean I can't serve static .py files through Github Pages?

I found the solution here:

The other option is to include the file .nojekyll in your top-level
directory which tells github to just serve your pages with out trying
to break them (this is useful if you are trying to post the oputput
from sphinx which does not need any more parsing/munging/rewriting).
relevant link

